# Matching string in column value returns none value

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Pyspark and have a dataset containing the column value "Company". I am trying to filter out results where Company matches "Microsoft".

Here is what I wrote:

```
new_df = file_df.filter(file_df.Company.str.contains('Microsoft', case=False, regex=True))
display(new_df)
```

This returns no results. I am not sure what is missing in my lines of code. Can someone guide me in the right direction.

Comment: seems like you got confused and used pandas API instead of pyspark in the filter condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spark [contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html) API does not allow `case` and `regex` in its signature

If you want the above `regex` capability, you can look into - [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.rlike.html)

#### Contains

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
file_df.filter(F.col('Company').contains('Microsoft'))
```

#### RLike

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
file_df.filter(F.col('Company').rlike('%Microsoft%'))
```

Comment: Here is what I tried:
```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
display(file_df.filter(F.col('Company').rlike('%Microsoft%')))
```
Gives me error: TypeError: Column is not iterable

Comment: Got it to work. Was passing the incorrect spark dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

display(file_df.filter("Company=='Microsoft'"))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).